# odbc_fetch_array not observing AS

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am using ODBC to connect to MS SQL server from PHP (5.5). Development is done on Windows 8.1, while production is CentOS 7. CentOS uses UnixODBC. Connection works fine on both system, with the exception of `AS` not being observed on the Linux machine.

Example:
`SELECT CustomerID AS CustomerNumber FROM Customers`

On Windows, `odbc_fetch_array` array key is CustomerNumber, but on Linux, it remains CustomerID. I have also tried `odbc_fetch_object`, which yielded the same results.

What is the cause of this, and how can it be fixed?

Update: Queries such as `SELECT SUM(SubTotal) AS total FROM...` results in array keys equating the result. Example: `array('10.000' => '10.000')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in PHP. Recent update to `PHP 5.5.25` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use the function     odbc_fetch_row()? I know it doesn't help you but maybe a workaround. I have also had troubles with odbc drivers not behaving the way they should have. In my case the error was in the driver itself. Maybe there is a new version available?